# asp-for list of values from select tag [in JS]

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I get the values from some select tags that are created in javascript?
The thing is that the quantity of the tags is not fixed.
I tried using select.tagName instead of asp-for but I cannot map it to a list property.

Simply what this function does is create selection tags for the clients of a hotel room. Every selection tag has all the clients names in it as an option.

Here is my property:

```
public List<int> ClientsIDs { get; set; }
```

Here are my selection tags created:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
window.onload = changeFunc;
function changeFunc() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('selector2');
    while (elements.length > 0) {
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
    var selector = document.getElementById('selector');
    var selectedValue = selector.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
    @foreach (var item in Model.Rooms)
    {
            <text>
            if (@item.RoomID == selectedValue)
            {
                var selectedValue2 = @item.Capacity;
            }
            </text>
    }
    var inputContainer = document.getElementById('for-input');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue2; i++)
    {
        var selector2 = inputContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("select"));
        selector2.className = "selector2";
        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.value = "null";
        option1.text = "Избери клиент";
        option1.defaultSelected = true;
        selector2.appendChild(option1);
        selector2.tagName = "ClientsIDs";
        @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
        {
            <text>
                var optionz = document.createElement("option");
                optionz.tagName = "ClientsIDs";
                optionz.value = @item.ID;
                optionz.text = he.decode("@item.Name");
                selector2.appendChild(optionz);
            </text>
        }
    }
}
```

The selectedValue2 is a value which is taken from another select tag.
How can I now get the data from the selection tag and put it in the List?

UPDATED:
Added the code from the main selector (from which the other selectors are getting created):

```
    <select asp-for="Reservations2.RoomId" onchange="changeFunc();" class="form-select" id="selector">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Rooms)
    {
        <option value="@item.RoomID">Стая @item.RoomID с капацитет @item.Capacity</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: `How can I now get the data from the selection tag and put it in the List?` from which selection and to which list? Maybe you can provide some html codes to help reproduce this problem?

Comment: This is literally my entire code from html:
<div id="for-input">
                </div>
That's just the container for the selection tags

Comment: I don't think you'll need more code for the solution. I just need to get the data from the selection tags and add it to list. The property that will contain all the ids that are taken from the selection tags will be ClientsIDs (the one I showed before^^^).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div id="for-input">
    <select>
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var clientIds = [];
            $("#for-input select option").each(function () {
                clientIds.push($(this).val());
            })
            console.log(clientIds)
        })
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: When I try this in my case: 
$("#for-input select option").each(function () {
                @Model.Reservations2.ClientsIDs. push($(this).val());
            })
I'm getting this error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: `@Model.Reservations2.ClientsIDs` this is c# code(serve side), which has already been render when the page loaded, you can not make changes to it in the js function(client side).

Comment: you need send request to the backend to change the data.

Comment: I need to get the data only once (when the user clicks the button) but the thing is that the user can change the values at all the time by selecting a value from the selection tags. I don't want to change the value every time the user selects a value but only at the end, when he submits the form. I want an alternative of this code in JS:
<select asp-for="Reservations2.ClientsIDs">
                </select>
but at the same time all this values to be put in a list.

Comment: So, can I assume there are two selection, after you select some value from the first selection and submit them to the backend, the `ClientsIDs` hold these value, then you want to render the values in ClientsIDs as options to the second selection?

Comment: exactly! That's true!

Comment: mj1313 I just updated it and put the code from the selector and added the entire function code. The thing I'm trying to do is: 
from a select tag to get the roomID and get the room capacity from this ID and create selection tags = to the value of the room capacity. And in the selection tag to add all the Hotel clients so you can choose which client will be in the chosen room.

Comment: I'm afraid that your function doesn't work too, I get Array(0) length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
 in console no matter what I do.

Comment: what does this for loop ( `for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue2; i++)`) do? I don't think you need to put the code into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230832/discussion-between-kraeror-and-mj1313).